# .Text is not working in .aspx.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is some portion of my code :

`//adding parameters with value
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", d.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", e.Text);`

Here is the related .aspx code

```
<tr align= "center"><td class="style1">Username : 
    <asp:TextBox ID="d" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td></tr>
<tr align ="center"><td class="style3">Password : 
    <asp:TextBox ID="e" TextMode="password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td></tr>
```

There is no error message for 1st .Text command. But for the 2nd line there is an error message :

```
Error   1   'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I don't understand why.

Comment: The `e` member of your page class (the one added for the text box by the designer) is shadowed by the `e` argument to your event handler (the `EventArgs` instance). Rename the control, or the argument, or both.

Comment: Always try to use more declarative ID names for elements, d and e are not that declarative. tbUserName and tbPassword would be much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", d.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", e.Text);
```

Is contained within an event which has `EventArgs e` as a parameter.

The event args has scope rather than your text box

Call your textbox something else. It's poor practice to give your controls such ambiguous names

Answer (score 6):

I guess your event handler and control name are the same.

Change the name of your control to for example `eTextBox` and it will work. Also change the reference in the event handler to `eTextBox.Text`.

Another possibility is the use of the `this` keyword:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // use this.
    string s = this.e.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly have overridden the text box variable in a method which has `EventArgs e` as a method signature. Use `this` to qualify that you want the class variable `e`, or better still, give your `TextBox` a decent name and avoid the issue altogether.

```
 void SomeBtn_Click(Object sender,
                       EventArgs e)
 {
       // Other code ....
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", this.e.Text);
 }
```